# Is it equivalent to say that a formula is logically valid and that a formula follows from the axioms?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, boolean-algebra

Lets say I have some predicate logic formula in Boolean algebra and I have to show whether the formula is logically valid. Can I show it by showing that the formula follows from the axioms of the Boolean algebra? Or can I only prove it for example by creating a semantic tree for negation of that formula and checking whether the formula is a contradiction and therefore not negated formula a logically valid formula?

Also, is it always the case that every axiom is logically valid? Why?

Comment: No, there is no need to prove by contradiction. And the proof by contradiction would probably require… the axioms.

Comment: You'd be very lucky if you could show that statement follows from Boolean algebra principles since boolean algebra does not involve quantifiers and predicate logic statemwnts often do.

Answer (score 1):

No, the axioms of Boolean Algebra are **not** logically valid.

[Logically valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)#Valid_formula) means:

> "true in every interpretation".

If they were, also the theorems (laws) of BA would be, and there are obvious [laws of BA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws) that are not true in every interpretation, like e.g.: $x+x=x$.

And yes, in order to prove that the above formula is a theorem of Boolean Algebra (i.e. that it follows form the axioms), you can apply the semantic tree proof procedure to the set [$\mathsf {BA}$ of axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiomatization_of_Boolean_algebras#Definition) and the negation of the law to be proved.